Usdc estimate gas "approve from the zero address"
I'm trying to estimate the gas for an ERC20 approve on the USDC smart contract, and while my implementation works both on Mainnet and Sepolia for any other ERC20 contract, it fails when I do so on USDC.
Does anyone have an idea what is specifically required to do so with USDC?
I'm using Ethers.js v5 and the standard ERC20 ABI.
My implementation looks like the following:
const erc20Contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ERC20_ABI, this.provider);
return erc20Contract.estimateGas.approve(address, amount);

Where:

contractAddress is the address of the contract
this.provider is Infura
address is the destination address
amount is a BigNumber computed with the appropriate number of decimals

The error I get is the following:

Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted: ERC20: approve from the zero address", method="estimateGas", transaction={"to":"0x1c7D4B196Cb0C7B01d743Fbc6116a902379C7238","data":"0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dead0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000","accessList":null}, error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":56,"error":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002445524332303a20617070726f76652066726f6d20746865207a65726f206164647265737300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","message":"execution reverted: ERC20: approve from the zero address"}}","error":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002445524332303a20617070726f76652066726f6d20746865207a65726f206164647265737300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"requestBody":"{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"to":"0x1c7d4b196cb0c7b01d743fbc6116a902379c7238","data":"0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000dead0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000"}],"id":56,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/d5ca672c9aa246ff9df442b72d89bc4a"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)

Given that the error mentions "approve from the zero address", I've tried, as in this example, to hardcode 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead or 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD as the destination address, but it did not help.
I'm not sure what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.
Solution
Solution was provided by Yilmaz. The Usdc smart contract required a from address when I called the estimation of the gas fee. I passed this information using the overrides option of ether.js v5.
export const ERC20_ABI = [
    'function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)',
];

class InfuraProvider {
    private readonly provider: InfuraProvider;

    constructor(private readonly network: Networkish) {
        this.provider = new InfuraProvider(this.network, API_KEY);
    }
    

  getFeeData = ({
        contract: { address: contractAddress },
        to,
        from,
        amount
    }: {
        contract: {address: string};
        from: string;
        to: string;
        amount: BigNumber;
    }): Promise<BigNumber> => {
        const erc20Contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ERC20_ABI, this.provider);
        return erc20Contract.estimateGas.approve(to, amount, { from });
    };
}



cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
ethereum smart contract wallets has two steps to execute a smart contract function. first they simulate the transaction which checks if the function signtature is correct. If it it correct, it executes the function if not you get the above error. With that being said, you are passing wrong function arguments.
ERC20: approve from the zero address
in solidity every type has default values. defaul value for address type is zero address. For somehow, from address is not correctly set, defaulting to the zero address.

Thanks for the answer! How do you explain then that it only fails for Usdc but, the exact same implementation with similar addresses works fine for other Erc20 contracts such as Uniswap, Tether or 1INCH Token? Or do you mean the from address within the Usdc contract is not correctly set?

Oh I think I got it now! Ether.js has an overrides option which can be used to provide additional parameters such as the from option. This seems to resolve the issue. https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-functionsCall

Now, my question, why did not you need to use ‘override’ in other erc20 contracts?

approve takes to and amount addresses, unless I am mistaking no other way to provide from with ether.js v5
